# Android - problem with file-writing

Tags: android, file-writing

I have some problems when writing an xml file onto my android device (GalaxyTab 10.1V). The code for writing the `xml` works fine. I can see the written file at the `DDMS` perspective in Eclipse and can save the file to any location on my computer. But when I open the same directory as opened in Eclipse with the windows explorer, it seems that the file does not exist! The file is still visible at the `DDMS` perspective, but windows explorer does not want (or can´t?) show me this file. After rebooting the tablet, the file is also shown at the windows explorer.

I have tried several things for solving this problem...

- writing a .txt file --> same result
- tried `getExternalFilesDir()` (as recommended since API Level 8) and `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` instead of `getExternalStorageDirectory()` --> same result
- writing at USB-Debug mode, writing at "normal" USB mode, writing without USB connection --> same result
- of course I have set the permission to read and write on the device at the manifest file

android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

- "show hidden files" is activated at the windows folder options

this is how my code looks like...

```
public boolean write(Result result) {
    Serializer serial = new Persister();
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Test/result.xml");

    try {
        serial.write(result, file);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

I use the [SimpleXML](http://simple.sourceforge.net) library for reading and writing my xml files but as mentioned before, the same problem occurs when writing a normal .txt file

Does anyone have an idea what the reason for this behaviour could be?